# http negotiate and kerberos

Tags: java, http, authentication, cookies, kerberos

Using kerberos with HTTP Negotiate mechanism,
I noticed that the client always
put in the request both of the following headers  :

```
Authorization: Negotiate [response]
```

and

```
cookie: XXXX
```

I also noticed that removing the first header :

```
Authorization: Negotiate [response]
```

the requested resource is still served correctly...

- Is it the right behaviour of kerberos ?
- Am'I missing something here ?

Comment: Servers typically use SPNEGO to initiate a session, then use some kind of cache *(e.g. a signed cookie, a Hadoop delegation token, etc.)* to limit the burden on the KDC service (and additional latency). So if your cookie is stil valid then the server would skip SPNEGO anyway. That's a possible explanation.

Comment: thanks for your comment ! can you help me understand what is a signed cookie ?

Comment: Look into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7119 for example...

Comment: I still don't get what it is...conceptualli I mean